# Unable to limit the data and disable the button using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I've created a table with checkboxes and i want to limit the selection of checkbox. I can check maximum of 3 in the list, If i check more than 3 then it should display that ***It should not exceed 3***.
I could write the condition but i couldn't `uncheck` the list (it is showing error message in the list while unchecking from the list). And need to disable the submit button when we ckeck more than 3 from the list.

Here is handleCheck function:

```
handleCheck =()=> {

if (this.state.Studcheck.length === 3) {
            alert("should not exceed three")
        }
        else {
            this.setState(state => ({
              Studcheck  : state.Studcheck.includes(x)
                    ? state.Studcheck.filter(a => a !== x)
                    : [...state.Studcheck, x]
            }));
        }
}
```

***Problem is I couldn't uncheck the checkbox after showing alert message.***

Can anyone help me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: how do you handle unchecking? can you add your component code as well?

Comment: If you want it to not exceed 3, the condition should be `this.state.Studcheck.length >= 3`

Comment: @UmairRamzan - I could not handle uncheck. That is the problem I'm facing

Comment: @HaoWu  - I couldn't uncheck the checked boxes once the condition gets true. If i dont write condition it is working fine.I could check and uncheck the list but when i write condition then i could not uncheck the list

Answer (score 0):

```
handleCheck =()=> {

if (this.state.Studcheck.length === 3&&!this.state.Studcheck.includes(x)) {
        alert("should not exceed three")
    }
    else {
        this.setState(state => ({
          Studcheck  : state.Studcheck.includes(x)
                ? state.Studcheck.filter(a => a !== x)
                : [...state.Studcheck, x]
        }));
    }
 }
```